# PySpark structured streaming apply udf to window

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to apply a pandas udf to a window of a pyspark structured stream. The problem is that as soon as the stream has caught up with the current state all new windows only contain a single value somehow.

[image: py]

As you can see in the screenshot all windows after  2019-10-22T15:34:08.730+0000 only contain a single value. The code used to generate this is this:

```
@pandas_udf("Count long, Resampled long, Start timestamp, End timestamp", PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def myudf(df):
  df = df.dropna()
  df = df.set_index("Timestamp")
  df.sort_index(inplace=True)

  # resample the dataframe
  resampled = pd.DataFrame()
  oidx = df.index
  nidx = pd.date_range(oidx.min(), oidx.max(), freq="30S")
  resampled["Value"] = df.Value.reindex(oidx.union(nidx)).interpolate('index').reindex(nidx)
  return pd.DataFrame([[len(df.index), len(resampled.index), df.index.min(), df.index.max()]], columns=["Count", "Resampled", "Start", "End"])

predictionStream = sensorStream.withWatermark("Timestamp", "90 minutes").groupBy(col("Name"), window(col("Timestamp"), "70 minutes", "5 minutes"))

predictionStream.apply(myudf).writeStream \
    .queryName("aggregates") \
    .format("memory") \
    .start()
```

The stream does get new values every 5 minutes. Its just that the window somehow only takes values from the last batch even though the watermark should not have expired.

Is there anything I am doing wrong ? I already tried playing with the watermark; that did have no effect on the result. I need all values of the window inside the udf.

I am running this in databricks on a cluster set to 5.5 LTS ML (includes Apache Spark 2.4.3, Scala 2.11)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could specify the Output Mode you want for you writeStream

[See documentation at Output Modes](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#output-modes)

By default it's using Append Mode:

> This is the default mode, where only the new rows added to the Result Table since the last trigger will be outputted to the sink.

Try using:

```
predictionStream.apply(myudf).writeStream \
.queryName("aggregates") \
.format("memory") \
.outputMode(OutputMode.Complete) \
.start()
```

Comment: tried that as well: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Complete output mode not supported when there are no streaming aggregations on streaming DataFrames/Datasets. Also incomplete windows would be no problem as long as they include all the data up to that point in time.

Comment: I am reading from a delta table with readStream.

`sensorStream = spark.readStream.format("delta").table(silver_path)`

Comment: Then I would try using the window function: https://databricks.com/blog/2017/05/08/event-time-aggregation-watermarking-apache-sparks-structured-streaming.html I don't exactly know what you are trying to do on the streaming data but maybe you should change the logic as well because indexing and stuff looks very procedural

Comment: I am using the window function :O. And the current code in the udf is just for debugging purposes. Ultimately the udf will do predictions with a keras model on the windowed data. The whole problem is that the window function does not in fact return the whole window but only the values from the last batch inside that window.

Comment: Exact I didn't scroll enough ! I'm not familiar with Spark Streming on Delta source and the documentation is not really clear about how to use Delta as a streaming source, especially for Structured Streaming. I think it's a missing parameter when declaring the source and you should ask around on databricks forum

Answer (score 0):

I found a [Spark JIRA issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-25756) concerning this problem but it was closed without resolution. The bug appears to be, and I confirmed this independently on Spark version 3.1.1, that the Pandas UDF is executed on every trigger only with the data since the last trigger. So you are likely only processing a subset of the data you want to take into account on each trigger. Grouped Map Pandas UDFs do not appear to be functional for structured streaming with a delta table source. Please do follow up if you previously found a solution, otherwise I’ll just leave this here for folks that also find this thread.

Edit: There's some discussion in the Databricks forums about first doing a streaming aggregation and following that up with a Pandas UDF (that will likely expect a single record with columns containing arrays) as shown below. I tried it. It works. However, my batch duration is high and I'm uncertain how much this additional work is contributing to it.

```
agg_exprs = [f.collect_list('col_of_interest_1'),
             f.collect_list('col_of_interest_2'),
             f.collect_list('col_of_interest_3')]
intermediate_sdf = source_sdf.groupBy('time_window', ...).agg(agg_exprs)

final_sdf = intermediate_sdf.groupBy('time_window', ...).applyInPandas(func, schema)
```

Comment: please add JIRA reference to your answer.

Comment: Regarding the edit I posted in the response above to get around the bug in Spark, the method works in the sense that it runs and produces correct results. I'm not sure about latency. My data processing streams that use this approach currently take anywhere from 5 to 10 wall seconds and I haven't yet profiled them in any meaningful way.